# Turn (progressively) `DeprecationWarnings` into fatal errors in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest, deprecation-warning, tox

Our test suite has many `DeprecationWarnings` from our own code. My team had been deprecating things without fixing (or checking for the warning) the affected tests. I thought the best way to solve this is to turn those warnings into exceptions or failing tests when running in the context of testing. In this way, the team won't introduce `DeprecationWarning`s without readjusting the affected tests.

Even more, if that conversion can be gradual (we have a lot of tests that we need to start fixing one by one) that would be great. Some sort of *allowlist* that I can reduce from time to time.

Here is the current scenario:

```py
import warnings

class Addition:
    def __init__(self, int1, int2):
        self.int1 = int1
        self.int2 = int2

    def get_result(self):
        warnings.warn("The method get_result() is being deprecated. Use result() instead.",
                      DeprecationWarning, 2)
        return self.result()

    def result(self):
        return self.int1 + self.int2
```

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from addition import Addition

class CustomTestCase(TestCase):
    # ...
    pass

class TestResultOperations(CustomTestCase):
    def test_addition(self):
        addition = Addition(2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(addition.get_result(), 5)
```

In case it helps, we are running these tests with tox.

Comment: Which test runner are you using?

Comment: I'm using tox and pytest.

Comment: Awesome choice - this makes it easier. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```py
class CustomTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
      allow_DeprecationWarning_modules = [ 
            "...",  # This is the allowlist, from where I will 
            "...",  # progressively start removing modules that
            "...",  # use deprecated calls
      ]  
      warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=DeprecationWarning)
      for mod in allow_DeprecationWarning_modules:
          warnings.filterwarnings("default", category=DeprecationWarning, module=mod)
```

The method `setUpClass` runs once, before starting with the tests. There, I set the action `"error"` to the `DeprecationWarning` warning category and I append "exceptions" to behave as `"default"`. Notice that this is test runner agnostic.

Comment: Do all your test cases have to inherit from `CustomTestCase` then?

Comment: Yeap. We handle specific assets there.

Answer (score 1):

No complete answer, but a couple of tips:

I know no way to do this gradually.

I would not generally turn all warnings into exceptions, as then also warnings in 3rd party libs would cause test failures.

Though, you can prefix test commands in the commands section of `tox` with a dash. Then also commands with a non zero return code can run and show errors, without making the complete `tox` run to fail.

I am pretty sure you can use https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS in order to turn warnings into errors, but I'd have to look it up. I am mobile currently.

**Update**

As you mentioned you use `pytest` as a test runner...

```
[testenv:businessasusual]
commands = pytest <your-tests>  # works as usual

[testenv:deprecations]
commands = - pytest -W error::DeprecationWarning <your-tests>  # works
```

... where

- the leading dash (inl. space!!) makes that the tox run as a whole does not fail, but still show the failures!!
- "-W error::DeprecationWarning" turns warnings into errors

Then you can either always run both, or only one of them via `-e`.

This finally means, the now test errors are shown, but do not break the `tox` run.